# How can I rotate <div>s and keep alignment?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a sidebar nav panel where some links are held and I want them to be displayed sideways. Here is the current nav panel:

[image: Currnt Nav Bar]

To break it down:

1. The Menu Icon

Here is the HTML for the Icon

```html
<div class="menu-bar-container">
    <div class="menu-icon-container">
        <span class="fas fa-bars menu-icon"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it's CSS:

```css
/* Menu Icon */
.menu-bar-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu-icon-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-icon {
    font-size: 19px;
    color: darkgrey;
}
```

2. These are the nav links, that I want is for them to be displayed vertically instead of horizontally, here is the exisitng code:

The HTML:

```html
{{-- Social Links --}}
<div class="social-links-container">
    {{-- Facebook Link --}}
    <div class="fb-link-container">
        <a href="">FACEBOOK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dot-icon-container">
        <span class="far fa-circle dot-icon"></span>
    </div>

    {{-- Instagram Link --}}
    <div class="insta-link-container">
        <a href="">INSTAGRAM</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dot-icon-container">
        <span class="far fa-circle dot-icon"></span>
    </div>

    {{-- Twitter Link --}}
    <div class="twitter-link-container">
        <a href="">TWITTER</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
/* Social Links */
.social-links-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.dot-icon-container {
    margin-inline-start: 30px;
    margin-inline-end: 30px;
}

.dot-icon {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

When I add `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to the `.social-links-container` class the result is like so:

[image: Nav links not centered]

How can I rotate these and still have them centered? Thanks!

Comment: try transform-origin. It'll be helpful to answer if you provide a working snippet

Comment: @SagarV This isn't a possible solution as this gives me the same issue where the <div> isn't in the middle of the 80% column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `writing-mode: vertical-lr`:

```css
/* Social Links */
.social-links-container {
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had to add `width: 100%;` but apart from that the solution is spot on!